# Silent redirect based on domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, debian

I've set up my own server.

Let's say my main server folder is `/home/www` and I've set the nameservers so that all domains point to this location.

**Now, here's what I want to do :**

- Have each domain's files in a separate subfolder
- Based on the domain requested, silently redirect to the appropriate subfolder

**E.g.**

- if we need `somedomain.com` or `www.somedomain.com` or `www.somedomain.com/anything/` (or any such variation for that matter) redirect the request from `/home/www/` to `/home/www/somedomain.com/`

How can this be done?

---

And here's what I've tried (but given that `.htaccess` is definitely ... *not* my thing, it'll most likely be close to non-sensical...) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?somedomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ somedomain.com [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible choices. you can create Virtual Host for each domain and set virtual document root.
Or 
You can use rewrite rule.

From apache Virtual host documentation:

```
# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/www.example1.com
ServerName www.example1.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/www.example2.org
ServerName www.example2.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

You can find out more in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Could you please give me an example? As for Virtual Hosts are we talking about tweaking the `apache2.conf` file?

Comment: Yes. you need to put virtual hosts in apache configuration file.

Comment: Great answer! That (or something along these lines) did the trick. Thanks a lot, buddy! ;-)